# css max-width works differently on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, media-queries

I coded a website and wanted to have mobile version and desktop version, my target was up from width 926px site should be in desktop mode, and i just had bought iphone 13 pro max, so i tested my site with it (production). Problem is, it only shows mobile version of the site regardless of whether it's landscape or portrait (on ipad it works fine on landscape and also pc works),

`@media (max-width: 926px) { ... }`

shouldnt it show desktop when iphone is on landscape and mobile when on portrait?
i got it working on iphones landscape when i reduced width to minimum: max-width: 831px

`@media (max-width: 831px) { ... }`

iPhone 13 Pro Max
[image]

Testing it on chrome dev tools it works fine when changed to landscape but on real iphone it doesnt work (for some reason needs to have max-width of 831px)
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's because the values you should be looking at isn't the screen size but the viewport size. CSS media queries work with viewport sizes.

Comment: @Terry as you can see i used 926px (viewport size) it is iphone 13 pro max landscape

Comment: _"shouldnt it show desktop when iphone is on landscape and mobile when on portrait?"_ : NO. Plus you shared a banner showing viewport size, screensize and device pixel ratio but didn't say anything about it. You have your answer there: screen size !== viewport size because hw pixel are not mapped 1:1. the media query as is will work if the viewport width is up to that value (and there are no other media queries or other rules overriding the style)

Comment: @DiegoD how do I calculate the correct values for iphone 13 pro max then? if testing it on chrome devtools works but testing it on real device wont.. ? and i used 926px which is that phones landscape viewport size

Comment: You have to subtract the notch and other eventual browser-ui. It's best to focus on the responsiveness/widths, and less on testing specific devices.

Comment: @niorad how to do this 'subtract the notch and other eventual browser-ui'

Comment: there's nothing to do, if you say "needs to have max-width of 831px" then that's because the browser is shorter than the iphone is wide.

Comment: @niorad so what is the reason being able to test different devices landscape portrait on chrome devtools if you get different result on real device ?

Comment: Devtools like these are always unreliable. Always test with the iOS-Simulator or a real Device.

Comment: @niorad but shouldnt media query work as is ? i'm using that iphones viewport size so it should work correctly on iphone and not when using chrome devtool... and do you know any iOS-Simulator for windows 10

Comment: From Windows you can use a service like Browserstack to test with iOS and all other common browsers/devices

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem here is related to how new iPhones report their screen size.

Changing your media query from using `max-width` to `max-device-width` should fix it.

[Source](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/iphone-safari-does-not-respond-to-max-width-media-query/336024/2)